# Column alias name being truncated

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Using SQL*Plus I'm trying to use a select union statement to combine the results of two columns from the same table like this:

```
select substr(startdate,4,3) milestone 
  from projects 
union 
select substr(enddate,4,3) milestone 
  from projects
```

Using the alias `milestone` for the column, but for some reason the result shows with the column name `mil`. It's being truncated for some reason, and I think the `substr` part is the problem since it grabs 3 characters from the `stardate` and `enddate` column. how should i fix this issue?

Comment: So. To test your theory have you changed 3 to a different value and checked the results? Otherwise, is it just that you need to resize the column of the database viewer you are using?

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a display issue.  What tool(s) are you using to display the results?  SQL*Plus?  Or something else?  The SQL language has no way of telling your front end how many characters to use to display a column name.

Comment: yeah i've changed the 4 to 1 and it made difference. im using oracle sql plus

Comment: Not directly related to your display issue, but it appears that `startdate` and `enddate` are dates and you're extracting the month. If so, you're relying on an implicit date conversion and an assumption about the date format mask; which may be an acceptable risk for what you're doing right now. In general it would be safer to do `select to_char(startdate, 'MON') milestone ...` to avoid ambiguity, and make it clearer what you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are using sql-plus. If I run the same query in my database GUI  (PL/SQL developer) it works fine but in sqlplus it just truncates the column header to fit the data.

I'm no guru on sqlplus, but this fixes the issue:

```
SQL> column milestone format a20;
SQL> select substr(sysdate,4,3) milestone from dual;
```

results in:

```
MILESTONE
--------------------
OCT
```

Answer (score 3):

You most likely need to set the column width.

```
COLUMN MILESTONE FORMAT A20
SET VERIFY ON
SET HEADING ON
SET PAGES 25
SET LINES 60

select substr(startdate,4,3) milestone 
  from projects 
union 
select substr(enddate,4,3) milestone 
  from projects
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this Help-

```
SQL> set linesize 100
SQL> column milestone format a25
SQL> select substr(startdate,4,3) "milestone"
  from projects 
union 
select substr(enddate,4,3) "milestone" 
  from projects;
```

Comment: That's not going to change how SQL*Plus displays the results.  It's just going to change whether it uses upper or lower case characters in the column heading.